# Store Text File in WP8 in Unity3d

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I'm Using Unity For Creating Games For Phone and I need to Store Some Data For Saves.
I Use `WriteAllBytes` for that Its OK in Android But When I Try Compile For WP8 I'm getting this Error

```
 "WriteAllBytes(System.String,System.Byte[])` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Assembly-CSharp.dll"
```

how Can I prevent This?

If I Can't use This Then Please Give me a way to store text in WP8.
Tnx.

Comment: Try this DLL I wrote for serializing things easily on Windows Phone. EZ_Iso.dll (Free) http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Comment: Tnx But When I Copy This DLL I Got This Error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies."

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Windows it says

Comment: Yes I Add This DLL To References And Code Doesn't Get Me Any Syntax Error But When I Go Back To Unity It Says "The name `EZ_Iso' does not exist in the current context" And IF I Copy This DLL in Assets Folder I Get Previous Error

Comment: You don't copy it into the assets folder. You need to add the reference in Unity. This link has the explanation on how to do this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/64570/how-do-i-use-a-c-dll-library-from-a-script.html

Comment: I Add DLL To Reference And I Use that on My Code But Unity Give Me the Error "The type or namespace name `EZ_Iso' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Well if you are doing what it says and it's still broken then I guess your computers broke. Sory bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solve My Problem By Use Source Code of EZ_iso.dll Directly in My Code And Its Work Perfectly Whoever I Still Don't Know Why I Can't Use DLL Directly.

Comment: I found Some Code Specific for .net 4.5 Maybe This is Why. Because Unity Don't Allow That.